# Find scale amount based on new dimensions

Tags: javascript, math

If I have an image that has 100 x 100 size, then I resize it to 200 x 200, how can I calculate how much it was scaled?

In this example the scale amount would be 2.0. How can I get that number from the known variables (original size, new size) ?

Comment: newSize / originalSize

Comment: you're sure it's not 4.0?

Comment: yes bc 200 is two times 100 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply divide the new height by the original height and divide the new width by the original width...

```
double xfactor = (double)NewImage.Height / (double)OldImage.Height;

double yfactor = (double)NewImage.Width / (double)OldImage.Width;
```